# Couldn't match expected type Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I need to make a list of case like `[B,N,N]` with a list that contain the index of the `N`like `[1,2]` here, and an int that represent the length of the final list.

Here's my program:

```
lignebn :: Int -> [Int] -> [Case]
lignebn i [] = []
lignebn i x 
    | i == last x = [N] : lignebn (i-1) init x -- line 101
    | otherwise = [B] : lignebn (i-1) init x
```

Here are the errors:

```
devoir.hs:101:17:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[Int]’ with actual type ‘Int’
    In the first argument of ‘last’, namely ‘(x)’
    In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘last (x)’

devoir.hs:101:29:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Int -> [Case]’
                with actual type ‘[Case]’
    The function ‘lignebn’ is applied to three arguments,
    but its type ‘Int -> [Int] -> [Case]’ has only two
    In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘lignebn (i - 1) init (x)’
    In the expression: [N] ++ lignebn (i - 1) init (x)

devoir.hs:101:43:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[Int]’
                with actual type ‘[a0] -> [a0]’
    Probable cause: ‘init’ is applied to too few arguments
    In the second argument of ‘lignebn’, namely ‘init’
    In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘lignebn (i - 1) init (x)’

devoir.hs:102:26:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Int -> [Case]’
                with actual type ‘[Case]’
    The function ‘lignebn’ is applied to three arguments,
    but its type ‘Int -> [Int] -> [Case]’ has only two
    In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘lignebn (i - 1) init (x)’
    In the expression: [B] ++ lignebn (i - 1) init (x)

devoir.hs:102:40:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[Int]’
                with actual type ‘[a1] -> [a1]’
    Probable cause: ‘init’ is applied to too few arguments
    In the second argument of ‘lignebn’, namely ‘init’
    In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘lignebn (i - 1) init (x)’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I don't understand what's going on, the code seems ok to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your recursive calls you need parentheses around `init x`. As it is, you are passing the `init` function and `x`. You probably also want a list of `N` and `B` rather than a list of lists of them, but it's hard to say for sure since you don't include the definition of your `Case` type.

```
lignebn :: Int -> [Int] -> [Case]
lignebn i [] = []
lignebn i x 
    | i == last x = N : lignebn (i-1) (init x) -- line 101
    | otherwise = B : lignebn (i-1) (init x)
```

Note also that partial functions like `last` are widely discouraged. Better would be something like this (untested):

```
unsnoc :: [a] -> Maybe ([a], a)
unsnoc [] = Nothing
unsnoc (x : xs) = Just ps where
   ps = case unsnoc xs of
          Nothing -> ([], x)
          Just (~(ys, y)) -> Just (x : ys, y)
```

Comment: Thanks it was obvious!

Answer (score 1):

`last` expects a list, but you have defined it in the pattern match as and `Int`

```
lignebn :: Int -> [Int] -> [Case]
lignebn i (x:xs) = ....
```

implies that

```
(x:xs)::[Int]
```

which implies that x is an Int.

---

On an unrelated note, in Haskell you do not need to put parens around function calls.  Don't call last like this `last(x)`, instead use `last x`.  It will work, but isn't idiomatic Haskell.

Comment: I edited my code but the errors are the same. For me, my `i` is the `Int`, my `x` is the `[Int]` and the output is the `[Case]`. Maybe my syntaxe is wrong?

Comment: I am not sure what edits you have applied, but I can tell you this....  From what you wrote above, it is `(x:xs)`, not `x` that is the type `[Int]`.  If this is not what you want, you will have to change this, either by changing the type, or the pattern matching.